# C# : Fastest way to remove duplicates point3D linked to indices

Tags: c#, algorithm, duplicates

Sorry for my bad english.

When you use MeshGeometry3D, you must specify :

- MeshGeometry3D.Positions : Collection of Point3D
- MeshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices : Collection of int

Each indices in TriangleIndices points to a Point3D in Positions. The TriangleIndices.Count is a multiple of 3 because you must specify triangle indices (so 3 indices by triangle).

The struggle is : In Positions, you can have duplicate points if you put them without checking if they already exists in Positions.
[image]

Here you can see that Positions[ 2] and Positions[3] are equals.
If you have 1 or 2 triangles, it's ok. But if you have 20000 triangles, it can be a waste of space + it takes longer to process large Collection (add items take longer, get item, remove item, ...).
So a solution is to remove duplicates Point3D in Positions. But if you do that you must change indices in TriangleIndices. If I take my previoux exemple, this will give :
[image]

One way to remove duplicates items in Positions is by using Distinct().
But if I use it, I don't know where he deleted the duplicates and so I cannot modify the TriangleIndices collection.
Another way is : When I add Point3D in Positions, I check if the Point3D (to Add) exists in the Collection and if so, I don't add it and I add the indices of the existing Point3D in TriangleIndices. But it requires that I use IndexOf which is slow... really slow.

So my question is : Do you know the fastest way to remove duplicates Point3D linked to indices ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The MeshGeometry3D class is defined with a set of Positions, Normals and TriangleIndicies. By definition, these three lists have the same dimensions.

If you need to save space, you could create a list of Positions without repetitions and a list of ints to store all the references to them for each facet.